# How to get CardView ID from its child TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, fragment

Hi I need to identify mParent in `TextView`, exactly `CardView` and `RelativeLayout`

[image]

I need insert in `SQLite` data by `CardView` and `RelativeLayout`of a fragment, which contains many `CardView`; so I need to identify which layout or `CardView`the data belongs to in order to make a cycle that inserts them.

I need `CardView`name, and `RelativeLayout`name

Comment: Hi MexiCano; there is a [`getParent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent#getParent()) method that you can get the parent view

Comment: layout = getParent().toString , this result is : android.widget.RelativeLayout{2371e4d V.E...... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0133 app:id/relap1}, i need name relap1

Comment: you need the id of the parent layout ?

Comment: Yes, I need the name of the layout where the textview comes from,

Comment: you can get it from layout with `R.id.xx` same like the id of the TextView itself right?

Comment: Yes, but i have multiple cardview, in need get textview data of each cardview

Comment: So, you've many CardViews, and each CardView has a wrapped-in TextView, and you want to facilitate accessing to all these card views right?

Comment: Yes, i need identify the cardview for obtain textview inside this cardview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've many CardViews, and each CardView has a wrapped-in TextView, and you want to facilitate accessing to all these card views from the TextViews.

I'll assume the id of the TextView is `textview1` and of the `CardView` is `cardview1`

Then To get access to the ID of the parent `CardView` using its child `TextView`:

```
TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
int id = ((CardView) textView1.getParent()).getId();
```

Also note that, you'll never get `cardview1` as a string as it's stored in the system as int value.

To make sure you get the right ID, you do some check like

```
if (((CardView) textView1.getParent()).getId() == R.id.cardview1)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cardview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @MexiCano welcome.. you can also add all the text views into an array to facilitate accessing them..

Comment: Hi, Zain, 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to androidx.cardview.widget.CardView in.....-----...... " TextView textView1 = v4.findViewById(R.id.textView5);"....------....
        " idcard = ((CardView) textView1.getParent()).getId();"
....-----....
the cardview is inside a linearlayot

Comment: @MexiCano can you share your layout please

Comment: yeah but here there is no RelativeLayouts .. can you share the xml code

Comment: Yes, this example layout: https://github.com/Luismx30/test/blob/master/textlayout

Comment: @MexiCano you have TextView nested in RelativeLayout which is nested in CardView; so the parent of the TextView is not CardView, but RelativeLayout  ... so you need to change the code above to: `int id = ((CardView) (((RelativeLayout) textView1.getParent())).getParent()).getId();`

Comment: Good Zain, thank, Zain one question how to reload fragment in button onclick?

Comment: Please Zain Help again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811228/refresh-oncreateview-fragment

Comment: Zain ,hi bro, i need you help in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942009/get-jsonarray-without-string-name

Comment: Hi @MexiCano I just add an answer, not sure if if would work as I didn't test it

Comment: Hi Zain, here again, I need your help on this post? greetings and have a nice day....-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391076/problem-with-convert-jsonobject-to-string-jsonarray-and-show-in-dialog

Comment: Hi @MexiCano I had added an answer .. wish it can help