# Get jsonarray without string name

Tags: android, arrays, json, rest

i need get json array without string name:

Code Select Sqlite:

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    String selectQuery = "Select * from capturas";
    SQLiteDatabase db = new MyHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Code Json :

```
public JSONObject createJsonObject() throws JSONException {
    Cursor cursor = getAllData();
    JSONObject jobj;
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("sCaptID", cursor.getString(0));
        jobj.put("sName", cursor.getString(1));
        arr.put(jobj);
    }
    jobj = new JSONObject();


    jobj.put("data", arr);
    return jobj;
}
```

I need the  jobj.put without "data".

Code JsonSend

```
  public void postJsonToServer() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject js = createJsonObject();
    String url = "http://xx.1xx.xx9.xx/server";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url, js, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Result json is:

```
 {"data":[{
    {
     "id": "22",
     "name": "test"
}]
}
```

I need json result:

```
    [
    {
     "id": "22",
     "name": "test"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an empty String key

So replace

```
jobj.put("data", arr);
```

with

```
jobj.put("", arr);
```

> UPDATE
>
> Result is : {[{ { "id": "22", "name": "test" }] } ....--- i need .....---[ { "id": "22", "name": "test" }]

Now try to use [Google GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson) to format the JSONObject you want,

add below dependency into build.gradle module level.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

and change the `createJsonObject()` to be:

```
public JSONObject createJsonObject() throws JSONException {
    Cursor cursor = getAllData();
    JSONObject jobj;
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("sCaptID", cursor.getString(0));
        jobj.put("sName", cursor.getString(1));
        arr.put(jobj);
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(arr, new TypeToken<JSONArray>() {
    }.getType());

    json = "{" + json + "}";
    jobj = new JSONObject(json);

    return jobj;
}
```

Comment: Result is :
{[{
{
 "id": "22",
 "name": "test"
}] }
....--- i need .....---[
{
 "id": "22",
 "name": "test"
}]

Comment: @MexiCano please check updated answer in the `UPDATE` section

Answer (score 0):

```
return jobj.data
```

instead of

```
return jobj
```

I think this pretty much solves your request alternatively you can use JSON.stringify to turn it into a string then use splice/slice methods to chop off extra and turn it back into array with JSON.parse.. but that would be wierd