# Problem with convert jsonObject to string jsonarray and show in dialog

Tags: android, arrays, dialog

i need help for show array 3 items in dialog

items in array : InvernaderoId, Name and Invernarder

I have a problem with convert jsonobject to jsonarray

JsonObject:

```
{"data":[{"invernaderoId":"1","name":"inver B","Invernarder":"inv1"},{"invernaderoId":"2","name":"inver C","Invernarder":"inv2"},{"invernaderoId":"3","name":"inv13","Invernarder":"inv3"},{"invernaderoId":"4","name":"inv14 A","Invernarder":"HTFRA14A"}]}
```

Convert to JsonArray with `JSONArray arr = js.getJSONArray("data");`

Result example:

```
[{"invernaderoId":"1","name":"inver B","Invernarder":"inv1"},{"invernaderoId":"2","name":"sd 12 C","Invernarder":"HTESP12C"},{"invernaderoId":"3","name":"s13","Invernarder":"sd"},{"invernaderoId":"4","name":"ds 14 A","Invernarder":"ds"}]
```

Code the replace array string:

```
  String[] arr2 = arr.toString().replace("},{", " ,").split(" ");
```

and

```
final String[] employes= arr2;
```

Code dialog:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setTitle("Selected one")
                            .setSingleChoiceItems(employes, itemSelected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                                    String nombreselect = employes[selectedIndex];
                                    employes.setText(nombreselect);
                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                            .show();
                }
            });
```

Viewer in Dialog select:
[image: Image result dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate through the JSONArray elements and add them into a String array, then feed your AlertDialg with this String array

```
final String jsonResponse = "{   \"data\":[      {\n" +
        "         \"invernaderoId\":\"1\",\n" +
        "         \"name\":\"inver B\",\n" +
        "         \"Invernarder\":\"inv1\"\n" +
        "      \n" +
        "},\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "         \"invernaderoId\":\"2\",\n" +
        "         \"name\":\"inver C\",\n" +
        "         \"Invernarder\":\"inv2\"\n" +
        "      \n" +
        "},\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "         \"invernaderoId\":\"3\",\n" +
        "         \"name\":\"inv13\",\n" +
        "         \"Invernarder\":\"inv3\"\n" +
        "      \n" +
        "},\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "         \"invernaderoId\":\"4\",\n" +
        "         \"name\":\"inv14 A\",\n" +
        "         \"Invernarder\":\"HTFRA14A\"\n" +
        "      \n" +
        "}\n" +
        "   \n" +
        "]\n" +
        "}";

try {
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    JSONArray arr = js.getJSONArray("data");
    String[] list = new String[arr.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length() - 1; i++) {
        JSONObject element = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        String InvernaderoId = "\"invernaderoId\":\"" + element.getString("invernaderoId") + "\", ";
        String Name = "\"name\":\"" + element.getString("name") + "\", ";
        String Invernarder = "\"Invernarder\":\"" + element.getString("Invernarder") + "\"";

        list[i] = InvernaderoId + Name + Invernarder;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Title")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(list, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }).setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .show();

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: Zain, hi, 
how to create a dialog to capture data  example: ... https://ibb.co/Khg4Vdk

Comment: Hi @MexiCano here you want to make a custom layout and the [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment) will be easy for this to add your custom xml layout .. then you can use a listener interface that you pass from the activity to the dialogFragment that you can use its callback with  the data returned from the dialog which is entered by the user

Comment: Hi Zain, help me in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518705/add-item-to-cardview-from-dialogfragment , please

Comment: Hi Zain, 
could you help me with this problem...-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781580/login-with-post-request-json

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[] arr2 = arr.toString().replace("},{", " ,").split(" ");
```

since you have an array, the easiest would be to pass the json array properly, create an adapter (EG. `ArrayAdapter<DataModel>`) and call `setAdapter` on the builder. In the adapter subclass you can control how the single entry is being rendered on the dialog