# RecyclerView cardview from dialogfragment in fragment page

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to create recyclerview cardview in fragment from the data that is written in a DiagloFragment

What would you do? How can I create a recycler view with the list once I press the button "HECHO"?

[IMAGE CAPTURE DATA](https://ibb.co/x7CvkWF)

Can you explain to me what should I do or even post an example please (done by you or posted somewhere else)?

Beforehand thank you very much.

DialogFragment class:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_captura_dialog_act, container, false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_capactividades, container, false);
    Spinner spinnerA;
    spinnerA = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerConf);
    bguardar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bGuaradrPaga);
    codigo = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tCodData) ;
    precio = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tPrecioData);
    preciounidadextra = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.preciouextra);
    cantidadminima = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tCanMinData);
    primadominical = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tPrimaData);
    final String tipojornada = spinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString();
    bguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code create recyclerview
            empleado.guardaempleado(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                    , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Card layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcodigoMostrar"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ajusted" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:width="2dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Apuntador"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNombreMostrar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:width="2dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Precio"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrecioMostrar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:text="Precio"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEditar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Editar"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Fragment class to cretae recyclerview:

```
      public class empleado extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
        FloatingActionButton btndialog;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        RecyclerView idrecyclerview, recyclerView;
        static List<ActividadesModel> listCont;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v5 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_empleado, container, false);
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = v5.findViewById(R.id.idrecyclerviewCa);
            //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
            AdapterAct viewAdapter = new AdapterAct(getContext(), listCont);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
            return v5;
        }
    
     public empleado(String codigo,String precio,String preciounidadextra,String cantidadminima,String primadominical,String tipojornada){
    
        }
    
        public static void guardaempleado(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima, String primadominical, String tipojornada){
            listCont = new ArrayList<>();
            listCont.add(new ActividadesModel("codigo", "precio", "preciounidadextra", "cantidadminima", "primadominical", "tipojornada"));
        }


 private void ShowMessage() {
        final String[] actividades = {"act1", "act2", "act3", "act4", "act5"};
        final int itemSelected = 0;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("Selecciona la actividad")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(actividades, itemSelected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    //  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {

                        // String nombreselect = empleados[position];
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String nombreselect = actividades[position];

                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("actividad", nombreselect);
                        editor.commit();

                      //  empleado.setText(empleadotext);
                    }
                })
               // .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(); // creating new object
                        dialogs.show(fm, "dialog");
                    }
                })
                .show();

    }
```

CaptureDialog class:

```
public class CapturaDialogAct extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
TextView textView;
Button bguardar;
EditText codigo,precio,preciounidadextra, cantidadminima,primadominical;
Adapter rvAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_captura_dialog_act, container, false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_capactividades, container, false);
    Spinner spinnerA;
    spinnerA = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerConf);
    bguardar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bGuaradrPaga);
    codigo = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tCodData) ;
    precio = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tPrecioData);
    preciounidadextra = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.preciouextra);
    cantidadminima = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tCanMinData);
    primadominical = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tPrimaData);
    final String tipojornada = spinnerA.getSelectedItem().toString();
    bguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code create recyclerview
            empleado.guardaempleado(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                    , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Model:

```
    public class ActividadesModel implements Serializable {
    private String  codigo ,precio, preciounidadextra, cantidadminima, primadominical, tipojordana;
   public ActividadesModel( String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima, String primadominical, String codigo, String tipojordana){
       this.codigo = codigo;
   }
    public String getCodigo()
   {
       return codigo;
   }
   public void setCodigo(String codigo){
       this.codigo = codigo;
   }

   public String getPrecio(){
       return precio;
   }

   public void setPrecio(){
       this.precio = precio;
   }

   public String getPreciounidadextra(){
       return preciounidadextra;
   }

   public void setPreciounidadextra(){
       this.preciounidadextra = preciounidadextra;
   }

   public String getCantidadminima(){
       return cantidadminima;
   }
   public void setCantidadminima(){
       this.cantidadminima = cantidadminima;
   }

   public String getPrimadominical(){
       return primadominical;
   }
   public void setPrimadominical(){
       this.primadominical = primadominical;
   }

   public String getTipojordana(){
       return tipojordana;
   }
   public void setTipojordana(){
       this.tipojordana = tipojordana;
   }
}
```

Add ADapter:

```
public class AdapterAct extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAct.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private List<ActividadesModel> actividadesModelList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

private List<ActividadesModel> actividadesArrayList;

private IAxiliarActividades iAxiliarActividades;

List<ActividadesModel> contactList;


public AdapterAct(Context context, List<ActividadesModel> listCont) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = contactList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   // return null;
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_actividad, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return myViewHolder;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name;
    TextView precio;



    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreMostrar);
        precio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecioMostrar);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Codigo para crear el listado de acitividades

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}

public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nombre, precio;


    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Mexicano, can you elaborate more ; I understand you have a DialogFragment in the picture that has a button and other stuff, and then what you want to do when you hit the button?... I cant get this point

Comment: Hi Zain, im edit my post, im need create a recyclerview cardview in fragment when click button echo in dialogfragment

Comment: So, you have some data (String of the DialogFragment spinner) that you want to send back to the fragment in order to provide it to the CardView right?

Comment: Yes, 
That's right, there are 5 textview and 1 spinner

Comment: When loading the dialog, write the data in it and click on the button I need to create the recyclerview cardview

Comment: can you show when do you fire the DialogFragment to show up .. I just want to modify this code , specifically the  constructor of the DialogFragment

Comment: Yes add in the post

Comment: In class empleado , method:  private void ShowMessage() {
 call class CaptureDialogAct

Comment: I already added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216515/discussion-between-zain-and-mexicano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to create interface listener for the the `DialogFragment` input to be returned to your fragment.

- **Step 1:** Create an interface inside the `CapturaDialogAct`
  `DialogFragment`, and an instance field of it:
- **Step 2:** Modify the `CapturaDialogAct` to accept an argument of this
  interface
- **Step 3:** Trigger the interface method whenever you click the
  `DialogFragment` button.

```
class CapturaDialogAct extends DialogFragment {

    ...
    
    // Step 1
    public interface OnSelectionListener {
        void onConfirmed(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima
                    , String primadominical, String tipojornada);
    }

    private OnSelectionListener mOnSelectionListener;

    // Step 2
    
    public CapturaDialogAct(OnSelectionListener listener) {
        this.mOnSelectionListener = listener;
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_captura_dialog_act, container, false);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_capactividades, container, false);      
        //..... reset of code
        
        
        bguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Code create recyclerview
                empleado.guardaempleado(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                        , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);
                        
                        
                // Step 3
                if (mOnSelectionListener != null) {
                    mOnSelectionListener.onConfirmed(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                        , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);
                }
                

            }
        });     
    }
   
}
```

**Step 4:** at your fragment, change the instantiation of the `DialogFragment` to implement the interface and handle the returned text with its callback

Replace

```
DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(); // creating new object
```

With

```
// Step 4
DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(new CapturaDialogAct.OnSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConfirmed(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima
                , String primadominical, String tipojornada) {
        
        // Do whatever you want with the received text from the DialogFragment

    });
```

**UPDATE**

> It already performs all the steps, it does not mark an error but it does not create the cardview, I will add the adapter to the post
> In Step 4 change the list of the RecyclerView adapter, and update the UI.

```
DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(new CapturaDialogAct.OnSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConfirmed(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima
                , String primadominical, String tipojornada) {
        
        // Do whatever you want with the received text from the DialogFragment
        listCont = new ArrayList<>();
        listCont.add(new ActividadesModel(codigo, precio, preciounidadextra, cantidadminima, primadominical, tipojornada));
        AdapterAct viewAdapter = new AdapterAct(getContext(), listCont);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.idrecyclerviewCa);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
        AdapterAct viewAdapter = new AdapterAct(getContext(), listCont);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

    });
```

**Edit**

You get an error as you define the RecyclerView as a local variable to `onCreateView`, so you need to select the class RecyclerView field instead.
So, the change

```
public class empleado extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    RecyclerView idrecyclerview, recyclerView; // this is the field class variable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v5 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_empleado, container, false);

        recyclerView = v5.findViewById(R.id.idrecyclerviewCa); // here is the change
```

Then, added `dismiss()` when you hit the dialog hide in order to hide it.
So, in your dialog fragment add dismiss() as below

```
    bguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code create recyclerview
            empleado.guardaempleado(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                    , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);
            // Step 3
            if (mOnSelectionListener != null) {
                mOnSelectionListener.onConfirmed(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                        , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);
            }

            dismiss(); /// <<<<< here is the change
        }
    });
```

Also made the adapter as a fragment class field in order to use it when you dismiss the dialog so created `AdapterAct mViewAdapter` in `empleado` fragment

Here is the your entire fragment after this modificaiton

```
public class empleado extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    //private static ArrayList<Object> listCont;
    FloatingActionButton btndialog;
    // public static TextView empleado;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    RecyclerView idrecyclerview, recyclerView;
    static List<ActividadesModel> listCont;
    private AdapterAct mViewAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v5 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_empleado, container, false);

        recyclerView = v5.findViewById(R.id.idrecyclerviewCa);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));

        listCont = new ArrayList<>();
        mViewAdapter = new AdapterAct(getContext(), listCont);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mViewAdapter);
        return v5;
    }

    //public empleado(String codigo,String precio,String preciounidadextra,String cantidadminima,String primadominical,String tipojornada){
    public empleado() {
        //  listCont = new ArrayList<>();
        // listCont.add(new ActividadesModel("precio", "preciounidadextra", "cantidadminima", "primadominical", "codigo", "tipojornada"));
    }

    public static void guardaempleado(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima, String primadominical, String tipojornada) {
        listCont = new ArrayList<>();
        listCont.add(new ActividadesModel(precio, preciounidadextra, cantidadminima, primadominical, codigo, tipojornada));
        //  new empleado();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        //inflate menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //handle menu item clicks
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //do your function here
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sincronizar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_sort) {
            //do your function here
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Buscar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_hoy) {
            //do your function here
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hoy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_anterior) {
            //do your function here
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private static String PREF_NAME = "prefs";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v5, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //public void onClick(View v5) {
        FloatingActionButton btndialog = (FloatingActionButton) v5.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        final String[] nivelItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nivel);
        final int itemSelected = 0;

        try {
            btndialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                //    JSONObject js = createJsonObjectInv();
                //    JSONArray arr = js.getJSONArray("data");
                //JSONArray arr3 = js.getJSONArray("data");
                //String[] list = new String[arr.length()];
                //String[] arr2 = arr.toString().replace("},{", " ,").split(" ");
                //@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject js = createJsonObjectInv();
                        JSONArray arr = js.getJSONArray("data");
                        final String[] list = new String[arr.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length() - 1; i++) {
                            JSONObject element = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                            String InvernaderoId = "\"invernaderoId\":\"" + element.getString("invernaderoId") + "\", ";
                            String Name = "\"name\":\"" + element.getString("name") + "\", ";
                            String Invernarder = "\"Invernarder\":\"" + element.getString("Invernarder") + "\"";

                            //list[i] = InvernaderoId + Name + Invernarder;
                            list[i] = Name.substring(8);
                        }
                        // final String[] empleados = {"Luis", "Daniel", "Juan", "Jose", "Cesar"};
                        // final String[] empleados = arr2;
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .setTitle("Selecciona el Invernadero")
                                //  .setSingleChoiceItems(empleados, itemSelected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                .setSingleChoiceItems(list, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    //  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                                        // String nombreselect = empleados[position];
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        String empleadotext = list[position];
                                        //empleado.setText(empleadotext);

                                        // SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                                        editor.putString("inver", empleadotext);
                                        editor.commit();

                                    }
                                })
                                //.setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // continue with delete
                                        ShowMessage();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                                .show();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void ShowMessage() {
        final String[] actividades = {"act1", "act2", "act3", "act4", "act5"};
        final int itemSelected = 0;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("Selecciona la actividad")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(actividades, itemSelected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    //  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {

                        // String nombreselect = empleados[position];
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String nombreselect = actividades[position];
                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("actividad", nombreselect);
                        editor.commit();

                        //  empleado.setText(empleadotext);
                    }
                })
                // .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                        /*   FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(); // creating new object
                        dialogs.show(fm, "dialog");

                         */
                        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    /*    DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(new CapturaDialogAct.OnSelectionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConfirmed(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima
                                    , String primadominical, String tipojornada) {

                                // Do whatever you want with the received text from the DialogFragment


                            }
                        });*/
                        DialogFragment dialogs = new CapturaDialogAct(new CapturaDialogAct.OnSelectionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConfirmed(String codigo, String precio, String preciounidadextra, String cantidadminima
                                    , String primadominical, String tipojornada) {

                                // Do whatever you want with the received text from the DialogFragment
                            /*
                                AdapterAct viewAdapter = new AdapterAct(getContext(), listCont);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

                             */
//                                RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.idrecyclerviewCa);
                                //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
                                mViewAdapter.addItem(new ActividadesModel(codigo, precio, preciounidadextra, cantidadminima, primadominical, tipojornada));
                            }
                        });
                        dialogs.show(fm, "dialog");

                    }
                })
                .show();
    }


    public JSONObject createJsonObjectInv() throws JSONException {
        Cursor cursor = getAllDataInv();
        JSONObject jobj;
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("invernaderoId", cursor.getString(0));
            jobj.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            jobj.put("Invernarder", cursor.getString(4));
            arr.put(jobj);
        }
        jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("data", arr);
        return jobj;
    }


    //Syncronizador de datos a servicio
    public Cursor getAllDataInv() {
        String selectQuery = "Select * from Invernadero";
        SQLiteDatabase db = new MyHelper(getActivity()).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from capturas where syncstatus= ?", new String[] {"0"});
        return cursor;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

And for your adapter, added a new method called `addItem` that accepts a new row in the adapter and notifiy change in last item.

```
public class AdapterAct extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAct.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<ActividadesModel> actividadesModelList;
    private Context context;
    private List<ActividadesModel> actividadesArrayList;
    private IAxiliarActividades iAxiliarActividades;
    List<ActividadesModel> contactList;
    // Este es nuestro constructor (puede variar según lo que queremos mostrar)
    private String[] mDataSet;
    private List<ActividadesModel> listCont;

    public AdapterAct(Context context, List<ActividadesModel> listCont) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList = listCont;
        this.listCont = listCont;
    }


    public AdapterAct(String[] myDataSet) {
        mDataSet = myDataSet;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // return null;
        View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_actividad, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    public void addItem(ActividadesModel item) {
        this.listCont.add(item);
        notifyItemChanged(listCont.size() - 1);
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView precio;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreMostrar);
            this.precio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecioMostrar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ActividadesModel actividadesModel = listCont.get(position);
        //Codigo para crear el listado de acitividades
//        holder.name.setText("nameprueba");
        holder.precio.setText(actividadesModel.getCodigo());
        holder.precio.setText(actividadesModel.getPrecio());
//        holder.precio.setText("precio23");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listCont == null ? 0 : listCont.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Zain, 
It already performs all the steps, it does not mark an error but it does not create the cardview, I will add the adapter to the post, thanks.

Comment: hi MexiCano please let me check

Comment: Thanks you so much Zain

Comment: @MexiCano here you go

Comment: Hi,  Process: com.example.actividadesdivemex, PID: 21010
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.actividadesdivemex.works.empleado$2$1.onConfirmed(empleado.java:263)
        at com.example.actividadesdivemex.works.CapturaDialogAct$1.onClick(CapturaDialogAct.java:84)

Comment: Crash in: recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter); .... and : ... mOnSelectionListener.onConfirmed(codigo.getText().toString(), precio.getText().toString(), preciounidadextra.getText().toString(), cantidadminima.getText().toString()
                            , primadominical.getText().toString(), tipojornada);

Comment: @MexiCano just updated the answer .. also plz make sure that you fill all the dialog strings  as if you use them in the RecyclerView CardView they'll be null if you didn't fill them

Comment: Yes , this variables data, error and code in next image: https://ibb.co/6rQZF4Q

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216654/discussion-between-zain-and-mexicano).

Comment: Help please Zain

Comment: Hi Zain , please help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781580/login-with-post-request-json

Comment: Hi @MexiCano I can't open this link .. can you check it.